# combineLatest do not emit even individual stream have value

Tags: rxjs5

My app is sort of complicated and I can not figure out the exact problem
The observation is the stream derived from `combineLatest` do not emit at the first time, while individual stram DO emit because they are all transformed somehow and used by other streams, so I am pretty sure they have value

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by `share`, I removed `share` in some place, and it can work as expected, Can not explain it though